# How does the iPhone X eliminate borders?

Tags: iphone

The Samsung S8 has top and bottom borders. The Mi MIX 2 and Essential Phone have bottom borders. Only iPhone X is able to eliminate all borders. How can that be done?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is the full story, but the screen folds over & wraps underneath - presumably this gives them space for connectivity.
It's OLED so needs no backlight, allowing them to do this.

It was visible in the Jony Ive presentation video - https://youtu.be/K4wEI5zhHB0

[image]

Comment: I imagine it will be. Generally display panels need one side with a thicker border for the connections to the panel. However, unlike LCD panels OLEDs can be folder with tight radii, in this case allowing the connections to be made under the panel.